# Unable to resolve Mapbox dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I have been trying to integrate some on new features from Mapbox into my app but gradle is. unable to resolve the. newly added dependencies.

these. are. the dependencies that are not getting resolved

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.0.0-rc.8'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-annotation:10.0.0-rc.8'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-locationcomponent:10.0.0-rc.8'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-gestures:10.0.0-rc.8'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-compass:10.0.0-rc.8'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-animation:10.0.0-rc.8'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-scalebar:10.0.0-rc.8'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-logo:10.0.0-rc.8'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-attribution:10.0.0-rc.8'
```

this is my. build.gradle file  app level

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a3dmapbox"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    // Mapbox
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0'


    implementation "com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.20.1"
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:5.6.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-building-v9:0.7.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-markerview-v9:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.11.0'
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0")


    implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.0.0-rc.8'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-annotation:10.0.0-rc.8'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-locationcomponent:10.0.0-rc.8'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-gestures:10.0.0-rc.8'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-compass:10.0.0-rc.8'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-animation:10.0.0-rc.8'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-scalebar:10.0.0-rc.8'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-logo:10.0.0-rc.8'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-attribution:10.0.0-rc.8'

}
```

this is my. project. level build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN']
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have configured the download token mapboxsdk is downloaded perfectly only the. newly added dependencies are making the issue

Answer (score 0):

They won't resolve because you are using old references, chamge them to the new sdk implementations. For example for anotations:

> implementation
> 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0'

**Reference**
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/guides/annotation/

Comment: thanks for your reply but the latest is v10

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I was not specifying the repositories for all projects, in my build.gradle project level it should be like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN']
            }
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```